Unable to deserialize the data into TValue
I have following code, which is setting & fetching data from Redis DB.
public void BulkSet(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> keyValues)
{
    if (keyValues == null || keyValues.Count == 0) return;
    var batch = _db.CreateBatch();
    foreach (var item in keyValues)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value);
        batch.JsonSetAsync(ToRedisKey(item.Key), json, "$");
    }
    batch.Execute();
}

private string ToRedisKey([DisallowNull] TKey key)
{
    if (key is ICacheKey cacheKey)
        return $"{_repositoryConfig.RedisRepositoryConfig.KeyPrefix}:" + cacheKey.GenerateKey();
    else if (key is string str)
        return $"{_repositoryConfig.RedisRepositoryConfig.KeyPrefix}:{str}";
    else
        return $"{_repositoryConfig.RedisRepositoryConfig.KeyPrefix}:{key.ToString().ToLower()}";
}

private void BulkGetUsingPipelining(HashSet<TKey> keys, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> cachedItems, HashSet<TKey> nonCachedKeys)
{
    var orderedKeys = keys.ToArray();
    var batch = _db.CreateBatch();
    var tasks = orderedKeys.Select(k => batch.JsonGetAsync(ToRedisKey(k))).ToList();
    batch.Execute();
    Task.WhenAll(tasks); 

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
    {
        var result = tasks[i].Result;
        var key = orderedKeys.ElementAt(i);
        TValue value;
        if (!result.IsNull)
        {
            if (result.ToString().TrimStart().StartsWith('[')) {
                value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<TValue>>(result.ToString())!.First();
                // I tried with List also
                //value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TValue>>(result.ToString())!.First();
            }
            else
                value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TValue>(result.ToString())!;
            cachedItems.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
            nonCachedKeys.Add(key);        
    }
}

In both methods Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is Dictionary<ClassId, HashSet<Security>>.
I am able to set the data into redis,
example: Key = <keyPrefix>:<SomeId> Value = [{"Name":"Test"}]
I am not able to deserialize the data in the BulkGet(), getting following error

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
into type
'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Digital.MarketData.Security]'
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
(e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
.NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'PpaSecurityId', line 1,
position 17.


The message indicates that the JSON you are passing to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HashSet<TValue>> is a single JSON object not a JSON array, see Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1.  To help you any further we need to see a [mcve], specifically the JSON string result.ToString() you are passing in.

For a [mcve] we would also need to know the type TValue in order to answer your question.
